# How to display only title field name in xl file using php

Tags: php, excel

Here i want to do read the xl file in php,here i displayed all datas that means in xl file i have four columns called **Title,Url,Visitors,Accesses**.but for me don't want like this , i want only title name how can do this ? [View my answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAjL3.png)

```html
<?php
include 'excel_reader.php';     // include the class

// creates an object instance of the class, and read the excel file data
$excel = new PhpExcelReader;
$excel->read('test.xls');

  function sheetData($sheet) {
  $re = '<table>';     // starts html table
  $row = 1;
  while($row <= $sheet['numRows']) {
    $re .= "<tr>\n";
    $column = 1;
      $cell = isset($sheet['cells'][$row][1]) ? $sheet['cells'][$row][1] : '';
      $re .= " <td>$cell</td>\n";  
    $re .= "</tr>\n";
    $row++;
  }
  return $re .'</table>';// ends and returns the html table
}

$nr_sheets = count($excel->sheets);// gets the number of sheets
$excel_data = '';              // to store the the html tables with data of each sheet

// traverses the number of sheets and sets html table with each sheet data in $excel_data
for($i=0; $i<$nr_sheets; $i++) {
  //$excel_data .= '<h4>Sheet '. ($i + 1) .' (<em>'. $excel->boundsheets[$i]['name'] .'</em>)</h4>'. sheetData($excel->sheets[$i]) .'<br/>';  
  $excel_data .= sheetData($excel->sheets[$i]) .'<br/>';  
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Example PHP Excel Reader</title>
<style type="text/css">
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}        
td {
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 0 0.5em;
}        
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// displays tables with excel file data
echo $excel_data;
?>    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by title name? explain in detail

Comment: Yes.I need only title name

Comment: you mean row ex. Title, Url, Visitors, Accesses?

Comment: Yes,In this rows i want only Title,no need remaining

Comment: Check my updation code,now i am getting but i need only title field values like Web Programming Courses,Courses Games and Anime,PHP: Hypertext Processor,Yahoo!,Facebook,dont want that heading,how to remove that heading(Title).see my updated image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By observing the `$sheet` array you will get Title at the position of 4,1 as follows.

By changing this line as shown

```
 $cell = isset($sheet['cells'][4][1]) ? $sheet['cells'][4][1] : '';
```

But it looks like you have copied this code from somewhere. It is hard to identify your need and modify it. Change the code as per your requirement and if any error occurs then post your question on SO

as per your requirement your `sheetData` function should be like this

```
function sheetData($sheet) {
  $re = '<table>';     // starts html table

  $x = 1;
  while($x <= $sheet['numRows']) {
    $re .= "<tr>\n";
    $cell = isset($sheet['cells'][$x][1]) ? $sheet['cells'][$x][1] : '';

     if($cell != 'Title'){  // check for title here
        $re .= " <td>$cell</td>\n";  
        $re .= "</tr>\n"; 
      }
        $x++;

  }
  return $re .'</table>';     // ends and returns the html table
}
```

Comment: now you should not use while loop as you want only a single column

Comment: Check my updation code,now i am getting but i need only title field values like Web Programming Courses,Courses Games and Anime,PHP: Hypertext Processor,Yahoo!,Facebook,dont want that heading,how to remove that heading(Title).see my updated image

Comment: I am not getting correct answer,before i what i am getting still getting like this only

Comment: Check my updated answer, how to remove that heading, that means Title

Comment: you need to manage it using ` if condition` see my updated answer

Comment: $cell = isset($sheet['cells'][$x][1]) ? $sheet['cells'][$x][1] : ''; Here we put static how make it dynamic suppose i want display URL means what will do? any possible way select field names